# java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass Can't find class (Forge 1.16.5)

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to load javax.ws.rs.sse.InboundSseEvent
But i'm getting this error -> "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/sse/InboundSseEvent"
But if deleting string with import, everything work's fine\

P.S. I can compile, but forge can't load mod
P.S.S. Other libs is loading good, Loader can't find only this class\

InboundSseEvent.java ->

```
public interface InboundSseEvent extends SseEvent {

boolean isEmpty();

String readData();

<T> T readData(Class<T> type);

<T> T readData(GenericType<T> type);

<T> T readData(Class<T> messageType, MediaType mediaType);

<T> T readData(GenericType<T> type, MediaType mediaType);}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the javax.ws.rs.sse.InboundSseEvent is in the java SDK of your project but not in the java SDK of forge 1.16.5

Comment: 1. Other classes of javax.ws.rs.sse work's
2. I dowloaded javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1 dependence